# Le mot « bibliophage »

Tags: étymologie, dictionnaires, grec

Je me demande pourquoi on ne trouve pas le mot *[bibliophage](http://titivillus.over-blog.com/article-bibliophage-116768632.html)* dans le TLFi. L'éditeur de texte même ne le reconnaît pas. Le Wiktionnaire en parle ; par contre Larousse ne donne pas le sens figuré . De plus, peut-on l'employer couramment avec le sens figuré  ?

Comment: Tu acceptes les réponses trop vite. Il est bon d'attendre ce que d'autres vont dire. Et en plus ça peut enlever l'auteur de la réponse de compléter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Réponse courte : tous les dictionnaires ne donnent pas tous les mots. Pour des raisons diverses, la plus courante étant souvent l'oubli. L'autre étant que la langue française est très conservatrice (raisons historiques) et qu'il y a une certaine lenteur institutionnelle à suivre son évolution. Le mot *bibliophage* est un mot récent employé depuis le milieu du siècle dernier.

En ce qui concerne le TLF, qui est une excellent ressource, il n'y a pas de mise à jour depuis plusieurs années. Mais si l'entrée *bibliophage* ne s'y trouve effectivement pas, le mot par contre s'y trouve dans la [liste des mots formés à partir de biblio-](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?24;s=3459323370;r=2;nat=;sol=0;).

Le très sérieux *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* ne donne comme définition que « mangeur, dévoreur de livre » (1955), donc le mot peut s'appliquer aussi bien aux insectes mangeurs de papier qu'aux boulimiques de la lecture.

Le non moins très sérieux *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* (comme le précédent dirigé par Alain Rey) donne les deux sens.

> 1. Qui mange des livres.
> 2. n. fig, par plaisanterie. Personne qui lit beaucoup.- adj. « Dans bien des cas je lis, je lis pour le seul plaisir de lire plutôt que pour avoir lu : je suis quelque peu bibliophage » (S. De Beauveoir, *Tout compte fait*).

Je ne dirais pas que le mot soit connu du « large public », il est certainement compris du public cultivé, qui, même s'il n'a pas fait de grec, connaît la formation des mots (ce qui s'apprend en France dans l'enseignement secondaire). Mais ça reste une image. Pas forcément une plaisanterie comme le dit le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française*, par exemple je pense que le mot était employé avec sérieux dans cette [émission de France Culture](https://www.franceculture.fr/emissions/la-compagnie-des-auteurs/umberto-eco-13-le-bibliophage) qui qualifie Umberto  Eco de « bibliophage ».

Quant aux correcteurs orthographiques des éditeurs de texte et autres, il y a beaucoup de mots qu'ils ignorent et c'est à nous de les éduquer.

Comment: Grand merci. Alors peut-on utiliser le mot couramment ? Les mots fondés sur des racines grecques sont-ils considérés soutenus voire pas répandus ?

Comment: Ça dépend, certains composés comme "démocratie", "aristocratie" ne sont ni soutenus, ni rares.  Mais la plupart du temps, je crois qu'ils sont relativement rares comme par exemple "érythrocyte" qui n'est pas soutenu mais restreint à certains contextes scientifiques.  On parle plus communément de "globule rouge".  De même "callipyge" et "stéatopyge" relèvent du vocabulaire spécialisé de l'art et de l'histoire de l'art sans être soutenus pour autant.

Comment: @petitrien Je ne parlais que du mot bibliophage dans ma réponse, pas des mots formés à partir du grec en général. Ce n'est pas clair ?

Comment: @Laure         Si, si, c'est clair, je réagissais à la remarque de Dimitris.  J'ai oublié de la lui signaler spécifiquement.

Answer (score 2):

On dit plaisamment et au sens figuré :

- dévorer un livre

De plus, *bibliophage* vient compléter utilement *bibliophile* et *bibliomane*, puisque le bibliomane ne lit pas forcément les livres auxquels il voue un amour excessif proche de la folie.  On pourrait aussi parler de *bibliokleptie* dans le cas des voleurs de livres.  Je crois qu'en fait la composition de noms à partir de racines grecques reste relativement productive en français.

Answer (score 0):

Complément des réponses : sans faute de ma part on peut dire également *liseur* (Référence : Dictionnaire des difficultés de la langue française  Larousse Thématique, p. 238).

> Le liseur est celui qui aime lire et qui lit beaucoup.